# Can't access file:// URIs when using a remotely hosted app

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova

I am working on an online Cordova app. I need to display an image from the SD card in the app. But when I give the path in image `src` attribute, I get the following error :

> "Not allowed to load local resource"

Any idea, how to approach this issue?

Comment: Post the possible code here.

Comment: Well that's difficult. Its too long. To simplify, I have a cordova app. Inside, I launch a external web page which has 2 buttons. One to click picture, one to choose image from gallery. 

I use cordova.getPicture to get the image through camera/gallery. This gives me image path. Now i want to display the image in a div.

I use this code : 

this.imageBox.html('<img src="'+ value.path +'"/>');

This gives me a broken picture, and error in console

Comment: In some old android, it display the image from gallery only. Android 4.4 doesn't display any. Also if i put the same web page locally, I can display both the image correctly without any issue. The only problem is when I host the page remotely

Comment: `value.path`. Please tell exactly what the string contains. `and error in console`. Please tell exactly the error message.

Comment: The string contains the image path like file://path-to-image.jpg. The exact error message is "Not allowed to load local resource"

Comment: Have you managed to solve the issue? I have exactly the same problem at the moment.

Comment: No I couldn't find the solution, and i don't think there exists a solution for this.